# Converting Namedtuples Returned From Modules to Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

When working with a namedtuple value returned by an imported module, `._asdict()` is not found to be a valid attribute.

My attempted usage :

```
>>> import os
>>> os.get_terminal_size()
os.terminal_size(columns=120, lines=30)
>>> os.get_terminal_size()._asdict()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'os.terminal_size' object has no attribute '_asdict'
```

Reading over the source for the os module I noted the following :

```
terminal_size = namedtuple("terminal_size", "columns lines")

# ...

def get_terminal_size(fallback=(80, 24)):

    # ...

    return terminal_size(columns, lines)
```

As the returned value is a namedtuple I would expect it to retain the functionalities this data type provides. I would expect the following :

```
>>> import os
>>> os.get_terminal_size()
os.terminal_size(columns=120, lines=30)
>>> os.get_terminal_size()._asdict()
{'columns': 120, 'lines': 30}
```

Despite the leading underscore, this functionality is documented and is commonly utilized. Link to this documentation and the source referenced can be found below.

I am new to namedtuples and I appreciate any guidance. Your time is much appreciated.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict
https://github.com/Snaipe/python-rst2ansi/blob/master/rst2ansi/get_terminal_size.py

Answer (score 1):

Indeed  -this probably can even be documented as a bug in the `.get_terminal_size` method.

What takes place is that it is defined in C with a "named-tuple" like object, but not quite a namedtuple.

The workaround, as you noted, is either create a "normal" namedtuple, and wrap the result of calling `.get_terminal_size()` into it, or, to just explicitly create a dictionary, manually supplying the values:

```
ts_dict = {name: val for name, val in zip(("columns", "lines"), shutil.get_terminal_size())}
```

(note that the "pseudo-named tuple" returned by `.get_terminal_size()` also does not contain a `._fields` entry, and the field names are not enumerable from that object - they have to be typed in explicitly).

Or, if you prefer:

```
from collections import namedtuple
terminal_size = namedtuple("terminal_size", "columns lines")

my_ts = terminal_size(*shutil.get_terminal_size())
```

will create a "conventional" namedtuple, with an `.asdict` method.

Also, note I've been using `shutil.get_terminal_size()` instead of `os.get_terminal_size()`, as that is the recommended call on the documentation of the later:

> ... shutil.get_terminal_size is the high-level function which should
> normally be used, os.get_terminal_size is the low-level
> implementation.